# how to make two primary keys for a collection in firebase?

Tags: flutter

hello I have 2 collection `skills` and `Providers` and the relation is many to many

in order to define a skill to provider I need make a new collection named

`ProviderSkills` which has `providerID` pk fk1, `skillID` pk fk2

so i tried this

```
providerskillscollection.doc(providerID, skillID).set({});
```

but I got errors

how to make it right? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But as far as I can understand, You need to use

```
final provider=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('providerCollection').doc().id;
  final skill = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('skillCollection').doc().id;
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('providerSkillsCollection').doc(provider+skill).set(
      {'date':''});
```